# Integrating $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)$ from $0$ to $t$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

I need help for solving the integral $$\int_0^t\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)\right)\mathrm dx.$$ I think that the indefinite integral $$\int\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)\right)\mathrm dx$$ will be equal to $f(x) + C$. Then, when I apply the boundaries to that result, I should get $$\int_0^t\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)\right)\mathrm dx = (f(t) + C) - (f(0) + C) = f(t) -f(0).$$ But I have some doubts if the indefinite integral I found is correct or not. Can you verify my result?

Comment: if you doubt your indefinite integral, can't you check it by differentiating?

Comment: Also, are you assuming that $f$ is suitably differentiable over $[0,t]$?

Comment: My function here was actually $f(x)=ln(g(x))$ for a function $g$ that is differentiable over $[0,t]$. So I think $f$ itself will also be differentiable.

Comment: I think your short proof is essentially correct. You must be careful that you only apply this result to functions with derivatives and antiderivatives defined from $0$ to $t$.  As given by @Randall , test our your result on a few well-known functions

Comment: The reason of my doubt was that I have seen $\frac{d}{dx}$ in an integral for the first time, and wasn't sure if it was supposed to be handled another way. Thanks.

Comment: @zzlawlzz  if $g(x)$ is ever $0$, differentiability will be a problem.

Comment: I think my $g$ will become $0$ as $x$ goes to infinity, so there shouldn't be a problem there too. Thanks again.

Comment: If $f'(t)$ exists and is continuous on $[0,t]$, then your answer is correct.  It is possible that $f'(t)$ exists on $[0,t]$ but is not integrable (Riemann or Lebesgue senses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For constant $C$,
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(\color{red}{f(x)+C}) = \color{blue}{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)}$$
So,
$$\int_a^b\color{blue}{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)}\,\mathrm dx = (\color{red}{f(x)+C})|_{x=a}^{x=b}=f(b)-f(a)$$
For $f(x)$ differentiable $\forall x \in [a,b]$. So yes, you are correct. In your case, $a=0$.